# changing direct links to route links

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, parsing

From my database I am grabbing a body column for website content.

For some reason some *href* are coming back without the dash (maybe getting escape) so `href="/my-page"` is returning as `href="my-page"` without the dash.

I need to know how I can alter the body column to look for `href="<some value>"` and add a slash to them. Only if it doesn't already have a slash, or it doesn't have *http:* or *www.* infront of it already.

Any ideas how I can parse through the html?

Comment: If you are going to display html in your view, you should use [HtmlHelper.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this for some rough processing:

1. Use `href="([^"]+)"` to find every link that actually points to some resource.
2. Iterate over each found resource (group 1 of each match) and check if it starts with `/`, `http://` or `www.`. If it doesn't, add a leading `/` and replace the original value in the code with the modified one (for the replacing, try replacing the value of the full match (group 0) with the modified value).

Answer (score 0):

This may be something better addressed in your link retrieval, but I think this should do what you're after:

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(href="")(?!www)(?!http)", "$1/"));
```

It will match and capture any `href="` not followed by either `www`, or `http`. Then it just inserts a `/` after the matched group. It may well be a tad flakey with more complex strings.

Comment: link retrieval is right from the database (which is our customers), and doesn't show up in the database

Comment: Ah I see, in which case I hope the above does what you're after =D

Comment: the link may be in the middle of a body, just remove the ^ I am guessing?. I feel like the above will just match href=" and remove the href and add in the /

Comment: Ah yes, edited to remove start of string anchor. If the above matches `href="` without the trailing www or http, it will keep the `href="` in tact (as the capture group will be inserted as the replacement string `$1`, with a trailing `/`.